# How can I "ping" a text file in a custom Unity3D Inspector?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm trying to "ping" a Textfile in a custom editor in Unity3D like e.g. using [EditorGUIUtility.PingObject](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/EditorGUIUtility.PingObject.html) (Shows the file in the Hierachy and flashes a yellow selection field over it).

The file is under  `Assets/StreamingAssets/Example.csv`

[image]

[image]

The simplest solution (I thought) would be to simply show it in an ObjectField -> if clicking on the field the asset also gets "pinged".
so I'm trying:

```
// For debug, later the filename will be dynamic
var path = "Assets/StreamingAssets/" + "Example" + ".csv";
TextAsset file = (TextAsset)AssetDatabase.LoadAssetAtPath(path, typeof(TextAsset));
EditorGUILayout.PrefixLabel("CSV File", EditorStyles.boldLabel);
EditorGUILayout.ObjectField(file, typeof(TextAsset), false);
```

But though the file is there and the `path` correct, `file` is allways `null`

[image]

Comment: Can you explain what you are actually trying to do?  Saying you want to "ping" a file is like saying I need to format my kitchen floor.

Comment: @Archer https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/EditorGUIUtility.PingObject.html see my updated question

Comment: Can you show a screenshot of where the file is placed?

Comment: @Programmer as said it is under `Assets/StreamingAssets/Example.csv` but I updated my question

Comment: I know where you said it was. I needed a screenshot to check for a typo since that happens here with many questions. How do you know that `file` is null? Can you do `Debug.Log(file)` to verify this?

Comment: @Programmer I'm debugging using VisualStudio and have a brakpoint on the last line ... `file` is allways `null` (see update)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My mistake was the typecasting to `TextAsset` and using [`LoadAssetAtPath`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/AssetDatabase.LoadAssetAtPath.html) which requires a `Type` parameter.

Leaving it "uncasted" as `object` (asset) and using [`LoadMainAssetAtPath`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/AssetDatabase.LoadMainAssetAtPath.html) instead which doesn't require the `Type` parameter works now:

```c#
// For debug, later the filename will be dynamic
var path = "Assets/StreamingAssets/" + "Example" + ".csv";
var file = AssetDatabase.LoadMainAssetAtPath(path);
EditorGUILayout.PrefixLabel("CSV File", EditorStyles.boldLabel);
EditorGUILayout.ObjectField(file, typeof(object), false);
```

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, your code is fine and this is a bug.

The bug occurs when the asset is placed in the `StreamingAssets` folder that is in the `Assets` folder. This causes the `AssetDatabase.LoadAssetAtPath` function to fail. I did search about this and only one [post](https://github.com/inkle/ink-unity-integration/issues/23) came up without any workaround. I mean you can use one of the API from the `System.IO` namespace to read the file but then you won't have access to the `Object` that references the file.

Possible Fix:

**1**.Restart Unity.

**2**.Create a folder named "Test" in the Assets folder.

**3**.Drag the `StreamingAssets` folder to this "Test" folder.

**4**.Change the path in the code to `var path = "Assets/Test/StreamingAssets/" + "Example" + ".csv";` then click "Play". It should not be null. If it's no longer null, move the `StreamingAssets` folder back to the Assets folder and also change the path in code to the old path.

The steps above is how I fixed it on my side and it works now. If that doesn't work, I suggest you move the `"Example.csv"` file to the Assets folder then use `var path = "Assets/" + "Example" + ".csv";` to read it. If it works, move it back to the `StreamingAssets` folder and change the path to the old path.

Another thing I suggest you do is call `AssetDatabase.Refresh()` to refresh the project. 
I also suggest you file for bug report for this issue.

Comment: Unfortunately that's not gonna work. It has to remain in the folder `Assets/StreamingAssets` in order to be able to change the file afterwards and still have it read in on runtime in a build. It is one of the special folders of Unity and accessed via [`Application.StreamingAssetsPath`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Application-streamingAssetsPath.html). What you do actually buy moving it to another folder is directly converting it into a Unity TextAsset which can not be edited in a build anymore

Comment: I am confused with your comment. I thought this is for an Editor plugin? By the way, I don't think you read the answer correctly. The final step says you should the move it back to `Assets/StreamingAssets` and your code should not work......

Comment: Problem is it works while the path is somewhere else within `Assets` but won't as soon as it is in `Assets/StreamingAssets`. The `StreamingAssets` folder is a special folder allowing to dynamically load in data even in a finished build. So a user can e.g. still change settings or labels afterwards. That is why it has to stay in `Assets/StreamingAssets`

Comment: Hi late answer but I finally found out that it was just a stupid typecasting issue. See [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52259365/7111561]). Thanks for your afforts, anyway!