# Unity editor ping class monoscript file from file path

Tags: unity-game-engine, unity-editor

I have a list of delegates i'm using for an event system. I'm using a custom editor that looks at the list of delegates and displays a button with the delegate's name. I'm wondering how I can use the [editor ping object](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/EditorGUIUtility.PingObject.html) to ping the script that the delegate lives in. I have the file path to the .cs file due to Delegate.Method.DeclaringType, i just don't know how to locate the monoscript object to ping.

```
                foreach (var callback in obj.Callbacks)
                {
                   // Path to .cs file
                   var path = callback.Method.DeclaringType + ".cs";
                 
                   // Button showing the delegates
                   if(GUILayout.Button($"{callback.Method.Name}", new GUIStyle(EditorStyles.objectField))){

                   // WANT TO PING .cs FILE OF THE DELEGATE FROM FILE PATH ON BUTTON CLICK 
                   //EditorGUIUtility.PingObject((MonoScript.FromMonoBehaviour(path));}}
```

I know similar questions are around on stackoverflow but I cant find any conclusive answers on the topic. Know that I have looked for a solution and am turning to the internet for help.

Thanks

Comment: Well, if you used namespaces that matched your folder hierarchy, that would probably work.

Comment: Afaik `FromMonoBehaviour` expects an instance of a type `MonoBehaviour` .. you can't pass in a path...

Comment: Maybe this helps: [How can I ping a text file in a custom Unity3D Inspector?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51401207/how-can-i-ping-a-text-file-in-a-custom-unity3d-inspector)

Answer (score 0):

I realized that the comment about namespaces not lining up with folder paths was correct, so technically i didn't have the file path either. I couldn't figure out how to get a filepath from type so that I could hopefully ping the file from what the comment above was mentioning.

I ended up going a worse route where I give the option to pass in the object (either mono or scriptable object) with the event call so then the editor could ping the object through MonoScript.FromMonobehaviour or Monoscript.FromScriptableObject.

I don't really like this solution but its the best I could get working. If anyone knows how to get the file path then ping the .cs file i would really appreciate a response!